# Why does this factorial limit hold for complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, factorial, gamma-function, analytic-continuation

EDIT: it seems implied by a response to this post that a proof of this fact does actually exist, but I've yet to see the proof or any intuition for the proof - so what is it?

OP:

According to a [Wikipedia article on the Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), given a fixed integer $m$ and increasing integer $n$:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n!}{(n + m)!} \cdot (n + 1)^m = 1$$

I understand this part, however the article proceeds to say that (emphasis mine) "we do get a unique extension of the factorial function to the non-integers by ***insisting*** that this equation continue to hold when the arbitrary $m$ is replaced by an arbitrary complex number $z$."

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n!}{(n + z)!} \cdot (n + 1)^z = 1, \forall z\in \mathbb{C} \space \ldots?$$

It seems to me that "insisting" is logically and mathematically weak. Why do mathematicians here get to *insist* this without explicitly proving it, especially considering how this result is used later in another proof? How does one know whether something is even fair to insist, without proof? It doesn't seem like an axiom or anything inherently assumable...

Thanks.

Comment: That section of the article isn't super well-written, but it's intentionally written in a pseudo-rigorous style à la Euler. It's not meant to be particularly formal. I think you appreciate such things more over time.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson I’ve satisfied myself simply by saying it is in fact an acceptable arbitrary assumption, since it has a logic to it, and what it’s doing is exactly what I think extending a function looks like anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the article means is there is a theorem, whose proof they haven't presented to you yet, that at least one generalization of the factorial function satisfies the desired condition. In fact, [it's unique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Euler%27s_definition_as_an_infinite_product). There are also [other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem) [theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wielandt_theorem) that highlight how this function is unique.

Comment: Where might I find a proof of the limit as extended to the complex numbers? In the article, this limit comes before the proof for an alternative definition of the Gamma function, so is there a proof connecting the original improper integral definition of the Gamma function to this factorial limit here?